# Silverlight Fisheye

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Does anyone know, if there is a (free/open source) "**Fisheye (Menu) control**" for **Silverlight 4.0** respectively a control which is similar to these examples:

http://blogs.nitobi.com/alexei/media/demos/feye1/2.html

http://www.nitobi.com/products/fisheye/alignment/

http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/fisheye-javascript-menu

Comment: Oh my god, those are *horrible* to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these controls are a good choice for you:

http://www.shinedraw.com/animation-effect/flash-and-silverlight-fish-eye-menu/

http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/08/21/coolmenu-a-silverlight-menu-control.aspx